# sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:bigquery

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, google-bigquery

Trying to create a bigquery connector using sqlalchemy

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('bigquery://<project_id>/<project_name>',
                   credentials_path=GCP_KEY)
conn = engine.connect()
```

Error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:bigquery
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your error is generally related to the lack of some required module to use SQLAlchemy.

Therefore, after going though the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/pybigquery/0.4.13/), I found out that you should install the requirements in you environment using:

```
pip3 install pybigquery
```

In addition, within your script you should import the following modules:

1. SQLAchemy

   `from sqlalchemy import *
   from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
   from sqlalchemy.schema import *`
2. API Client

   `from pybigquery.api import ApiClient`

Afterwards, you should have all the necessary packages to execute your code.

If you have any more question about using the SQLAlchemy and API client for BigQuery, you can consult the provided documentation above or I would also be glad to help.

Comment: I am having the same issue but with `access.pyodbc` I tried everything I can. [Here is my post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63699178/5110035)