# PyInstaller not including sqlalchemy-access module

Tags: python, pyinstaller, sqlalchemy-access

I am trying to write a Dataframe back into a Access database file `.mdb` or `.accdb`. I am using `sqlalchemy` and `sqlalchemy-access` to create a connection.

```py
import sqlalchemy

db_file_path = os.path.join(dir_path, f"data\\{graph_name}\\results\\{file_name}")
connection_string = (r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};' f"DBQ={db_file_path};" r'ExtendedAnsiSQL=1;')
connection_url = f"access+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={urllib.parse.quote_plus(connection_string)}"
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(connection_url)
text_labels.to_sql('InstTextLabels', engine, index=False, if_exists='append')
```

I have `pyodbc` and `sqlalchemy-access` installed via `pip`. If I were to run this in Python interactive shell or Jupyter Notebook, it all works. But when I build a one file executable with PyInstaller I get:

```py
File "solver.py", line 499, in main
export_results(file_name, graph_name, downstream_low, downstream_high, objective_results, objective_fuses, objective_recloseres, nodes, text_labels, dir_path)
File "solver.py", line 399, in export_results
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(connection_url)
File "sqlalchemy\engine\__init__.py", line 500, in create_engine
File "sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 61, in create
File "sqlalchemy\engine\url.py", line 172, in _get_entrypoint
File "sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 267, in load
sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:access.pyodbc
[5880] Failed to execute script solver
```

I don't know why this keeps happening. My script only imports `sqlalchemy` but I also included `hiddenimports=['sqlalchemy_access', 'pyodbc']` in the `.spec` file. Yet, nothing helps.

Comment: Can this solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60294040/sqlalchemy-exc-nosuchmoduleerror-cant-load-plugin-sqlalchemy-dialectsbigquer?

Comment: @Giovanni Nope. Still same error! I am so stumped right now, I don't even know what to do.

Comment: This issue has been resolved on GitHub [here](https://github.com/gordthompson/sqlalchemy-access/issues/10).

Comment: @GordThompson do you want to post a simple answer linking to the GitHub issue so I can set it as the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Add these import along with sqlalchemy:

```python
import sqlalchemy_access as sa_a
import sqlalchemy_access.pyodbc as sa_a_pyodbc
```